# Disable Status Bar Android 4+

Tags: android

I see the answer often for this is that it is not possible.  I assume that google does not want you to do this.  But I am building a kiosk app.  I know it is possible because this application does it:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.procoit.kioskbrowser

So install the application and open it.  If you scroll down on the status bar on the top it shows the status bar but never expands it.

I assume they are doing something hacky but I want to be able to do that.  Any thoughts on what they are doing?

Answer (score 0):

try this..its working for me..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,windowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.about_app_phone);

}
```

Comment: Is this code to just hide the status bar?  If you pull from the top it  still shows the status bar.  Download the app I mentioned above I want it to work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Default implementation of android doesnt support disabling of status bar,In my application I have used the reflection to invoke the statusbarmanager.You can also do the same thing.

```
Object lStatusBarSvc = getSystemService("statusbar");
Class<?> lStatusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");

Method collapse = lStatusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
collapse.setAccessible(true);
collapse.invoke(lStatusBarSvc);
```

Comment: This just collapses it when it shows correct?  Did you see the example app?  It is possible.  It works on my phone which is not rooted

Answer (score 0):

We could not prevent the status appearing in full screen mode in kitkat devices, so made a hack which still suits the requirement ie block the status bar from expanding.

For that to work, the app was not made full screen. We put a overlay over status bar and consumed all input events. It prevented the status from expanding.

***note:***

- customViewGroup is custom class which extends any
  layout(frame,relative layout etc) and consumes touch event.
- to consume touch event override the onInterceptTouchEvent method of
  the view group and return true

**Updated**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

[customViewGroup implementation](https://gist.github.com/sarme/7e4dc90e2478ade310e6)
Code :

```
WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

            // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |

            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    localLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 * getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

    customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(this);

    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

Hope this helps you